# Get Image and intro text from wagtail page chooser

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I am incorporating a page chooser in wagtail admin, however what I want to get is the image for each item in the streamblock for the page chooser and was wanting to know if there is a way to do this. So lets say if I have a category index page I would have the following code:

```
{% if page.case_study %}
                            
   {% image page.case_study.image fill-50x50-c100 class="" %}
   {{ page.case_study }}
                           
{% endif %}
```

All I seem to get are the links which is fine, but I need the image from that case study page. My model is as follows:

```
class CategoryPage(Page):
"""
Detail view for a specific category
"""
introduction = RichTextField(
    help_text='Text to describe the page',
    blank=True)
image = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+',
    help_text='Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.'
)
body = StreamField(
    BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Page body", blank=True
)
case_study = StreamField([
    ('Cases', blocks.PageChooserBlock()),
], blank=True,
   null=True,
   verbose_name='Case Studies',
)
origin = models.ForeignKey(
    Country,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

category_type = models.ForeignKey(
    'categories.CategoryType',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
)

categories = ParentalManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('introduction', classname="full"),
    ImageChooserPanel('image'),
    StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    StreamFieldPanel('case_study'),
    FieldPanel('origin'),
    FieldPanel('category_type'),
]

search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
    index.SearchField('body'),
]

parent_page_types = ['CategoriesIndexPage']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A StreamField is a list of blocks, but when you write `page.case_study.image` you're trying to access it as if it's only a single item. I'd suggest you start by updating your field / block names to make this distinction clearer - `case_studies` is the list, and each block in it is a single `case` (note that conventionally block names are lower-case):

```
case_studies = StreamField(
    [
         ('case', blocks.PageChooserBlock()),
    ],
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name='Case Studies',
)
```

In your template, you will now loop over `page.case_studies`. However, this will not give you the case study page objects directly - each item in the list is a 'block' object, with `block_type` and `value` properties. This is because a StreamField usually involves mixing multiple block types (rather than just the one type you've defined here) and in that situation, you need some way of finding out what block type you're working with on each iteration of the loop.

```
{% if page.case_studies %}
    {% for block in page.case_studies %}
         {# block.value now refers to the page object #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The next issue is that your `PageChooserBlock` currently lets you select any page type. This means that when your template is rendered, it has no way to know up-front which page type to retrieve, so (in order to avoid unnecessary database lookups) it returns it as a basic `Page` instance which only contains the core fields that are common to all pages, such as `title` and `slug` - consequently, your `image` field will not be available through `block.value.image`. You can get around this by using `block.value.specific.image` which performs the extra database lookup to retrieve the complete page data - however, a more efficient approach is to specify the page type on the PageChooserBlock (assuming you've set up a dedicated page type for your case studies):

```
    ('case', blocks.PageChooserBlock(page_type=CaseStudyPage)),
```

Your final template code then becomes:

```
{% if page.case_studies %}
    {% for block in page.case_studies %}
         {% image block.value.image fill-50x50-c100 class="" %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```